# Is the problem to construct a $\mathcal{O}\mbox{*}(1.4^n)$ (or better) time algorithm for subset sum still open?

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, np-complete

Is the problem to construct a $\mathcal{O}\mbox{*}(1.4^n)$ (or better) time algorithm for subset sum still open? I wanted to check the problem before finishing a paper.

The most recent reference I found to this open problem is on next paper:

> 'SETH-Based Lower Bounds for Subset Sum and Bicriteria Path, Amir
>   Abboud et al.' 2017
>   [link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.04546v1)

citing:

> 'Open problems around exact algorithms, Woeginger' 2008 
>   [link](http://faculty.cs.tamu.edu/chen/courses/cpsc669/2011/notes/ww1.pdf).

Comment: It's probably still open. If not, you would probably find out about it in your literature search.

Comment: found another paper, from May/18 stating is still open, so I'll assume is open and move forward, thanks!

Comment: People will cite your paper once published , "Yup, it is still open!".

Comment: @JohnL. I did not notice your comment back in the day... you are fun :D. This is my educated guess... either you tried for like 5 minutes and failed, or you never tried and your mindset is just stagnant. I broke trough that Time Complexity long time ago, why the paper is not publish is a matter of personal preference and objectives. Guess we will need to wait to see what really happens... ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to tell if it is open is to read more recent papers to see if any of them make progress.  If not, it's still open.  The way to find more recent papers is to look up that paper on Google Scholar and look through all the papers that site it.  If someone has made progress, it's likely they'll cite that paper.

In general, don't expect to necessarily find a paper somewhere that says "it's still open".  People aren't necessarily going to bother repeating "yup, still open" every year.